# Access Form combo-box selection to launch url entries unique to each record

Tags: vba, ms-access

Please let me know if it’s possible to accomplish the following in Access 2010.

Table “tbl_Genes” contains a primary field: “GeneID”--Number, “GeneName”--Text and Memo fields: “Cosmic”, “UniProt”, “Google”and “PubMed” that contain a unique Url for each record. Please see the attached example.

[image]

On a continues form, for each record I would like to list all four hyperlink types: Cosmic, Uniprot, Google and PubMed inside a combo-box. When the user clicks on desired combo-box item, the corresponding website will launch. I’m not sure how to connect the combo-box to records in “tbl_Genes” table to make this work.

Please suggest how to link selection on the combo-box to Urls listed in the tbl_Genes for each record.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should *normalize* your database to have the URLs in a subtable.

But you can use the *OnCurrent* event of the form to fill the combobox (set its *RowSourceType* property to *ValueList*):

```
Me!ComboUrl.RowSource = Me!Cosmic.Value & ";" & Me!UniProt.Value & ";" & Me!Google.Value & ";" & Me!PubMed.Value
```